# scrapy get image size without downloading

Tags: image, download, scrapy, size

I want to get image size without download, is it possible?

image1 url:https://koctas-img.mncdn.com/mnresize/600/600/productimages/1000599303/1000599303_1_MC/8843182866482_1663925809606.jpg

```
def parse_product(self, response):

    images = response.css(".swiper-slide::attr(data-large)").getall()
    image1 = images[0]
    image_size=yield Request(image1, method="HEAD", callback=self.callback)
```

Comment: Do you mean dimensions or size in bytes?

Comment: I am not really sure if that is possible. However, I'd be interested to know that. I have known that sometimes the image URL itself includes the image dimensions. But size would be unpredictable unless you have the image downloaded itself.

Comment: only  size in bytes

Comment: Actually it is possible in requets but i couldn't apply it in scrapy                          
                                                                                                                               
  import requests

url = r"https://sportive.akinoncdn.com/products/2022/01/12/368550/de43ce22-ab91-47b1-a160-7f11d830ca9c.jpg"

size = requests.get(url, stream = True).headers['Content-length']
print(size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/methods/head) method.

```py
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example_spider'

    def start_requests(self):
        images_urls = [
            'http://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1809904.jpg',
            'https://i2.wp.com/www.otakutale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man-Anime-Magazine-Visual-01.jpg',
            'https://thedeadtoons.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/One-Punch-Man-Season-3.jpg'
        ]
        for url in images_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method='HEAD')

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        yield {
            'Content-Length': response.headers['Content-Length']
        }
```

**Output:**

```py
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://thedeadtoons.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/One-Punch-Man-Season-3.jpg>
{'Content-Length': b'179681'}
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://i2.wp.com/www.otakutale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man-Anime-Magazine-Visual-01.jpg>
{'Content-Length': b'1847153'}
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1809904.jpg>
{'Content-Length': b'246144'}
```